# Getting “Procfile declares types -> (none)” in Heroku as an error when I deploy

Tags: heroku, procfile, reveal.js

am trying to deploy a test app to Heroku but every time I do my Procfile is being ignored.

It should be saying this:

> Procfile declares types -> web

But says this

> Procfile declares types -> (none)

Because of this problem it of course won't load on the heroku platform when I navigate the URL.

I added a Procfile to the root directory of the app, and in the procfile I put:

```
web: sh target/bin/webapp
```

Still no go. The Procfile is properly named and cased.

Comment: What buildpack is being picked up?  It's one of the first lines displayed.  ie. 
```
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Node.js app detected
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your procfile does not have any extension in file name if you are using windows